# What is -w operator in unix-shell conditions?

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, sh

it seems that it works as an 
inversion...
example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
#a=1
b=2
 if [ "$a"  -o -w  "$b" ]; then
   echo "ok"
 else 
   echo "fail"
 fi
```

Returns "fail".

but I'm not sure, because

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
#a=1
#b=2
 if [ "$a"  -o -w  "$b" ]; then
   echo "ok"
 else 
   echo "fail"
 fi
```

Also returns "fail". If replace -w on ! this returns "ok".

Show me, please, where is documented this operator. Bash and sh manuals contain  -a and -o  operators only.

Comment: The `bash` man page entry for `test` only mentions `-a` and `-o` by name, but it does refer you to the section on conditional expressions where the other primaries are documented. By the way, `-a` and `-o` are considered obsolete; you should use `[ "$a" ] || [ -w "$b' ]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is documented in `man bash`, and the same excerpt is available through `help test`:

```
  -w FILE        True if the file is writable by you.
```

Answer (score 2):

It tests if the file exists and is writable. Read the manual of the `test` command.

Comment: Because `[` is actually a command, almost identical to the `test` command (the difference is that `[` requires `]` as its last argument).

Comment: `test` and `[` are excatly the same command, they are actually two links on the same binary file.

Comment: Thanks. I know -w FILE, but   I didn't know that it is possible to apply for number value from variable. with strace I see how it works.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès `test` and `[` are both `bash` shell builtins.  The documentation is in `man bash`.  Often, systems also have a `test` executable that is accessible as `/usr/bin/test`.  It is that executable, not the bash builtin, that is documented by `man test`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Even if they're the same executable, they behave slightly differently. `test -f filename ]` is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Just some additional info:

```
[ -e file ] : if "file" exists
[ -f file ] : if "file" exists and it is a file
[ -s file ] : if "file" exists and it is not empty
[ -d file ] : to check if "file" exists and it is a directory
[ -r file ] : if "file" exists and readable
[ -w file ] : if "file" exists and writable
[ -x file ] : if "file" exists and it is executable
[ -O file ] : if "file" exists and it is owned by current user
[ -G file ] : if "file" exists and default group same as the current user
[ file_1 -nt file_2 ] : if "file_1" newer than "file_2"
[ file_1 -ot file_2 ] : if "file_1" older than "file_2"
```